# window.requestFileSystem not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I am trying on Firefox,IE 9,Chrome and Opera the code below ,but the onInitFs(fs) function doesn't get called.if I  add '()' to onInitFs in the window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler) that function get called but fs is null ?
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?I try on windows 7.I'll appreciate very much your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
`<html>
    <head>  
    <script>
        function errorHandler(e){
            alert("errorrrr");
        }
        function onInitFs(fs){
        alert("onInitFs");
        }
        function readClick(){
                 if (window.webkitRequestFileSystem) {
                     window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024,onInitFs,errorHandler);
                } 
                 else {
                    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
                }

            alert("read finishsssss");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Read dir" onclick="readClick()">
    <ul id="filelist"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802032/how-can-a-chrome-extension-save-many-files-to-a-user-specified-directory/19813816#comment71099517_19813816

Answer (score 14):

Only chrome supports `requestFileSystem` as the `webkitRequestFileSystem` version.

None of the other browsers (FF6, IE9, Op11) support this

Comment: 1.thnx but I am trying on chrome as well with webkitRequestFileSystem and the onInitFs(fs) function doesn't work ie doesn't get called

Comment: 2.my second question is:do you now any way of getting the list of files of a given folder which would work in almost all browsers?

Comment: @Tony2 no. requestFileSystem gives you a sandboxed file system. You cant access local files directly. You can ask users to upload a file through `<input type='file' />` though

Comment: i appreciate very much your responses,but i don't want to ask user.I  need to load from code one by one the images of a given folder without using the trick of naming images like this image1.jpg,image2.jpg,etc in other words images'names are unchangeable   .any idea?

Comment: there will be about 100 images

Comment: @tony2 **You cannot arbitarly access local files using javascript**

Comment: thank you very much.what if i use php ?can be done any trickby using it for client side please help

Comment: @Tony2 the only way to access local files on a users computer would be to use ActiveX (IE only) or Java. Be wary that your **forced to use those to bypass security checks**. Browser **do not allow you to access local files because it's unsecure**

Comment: @Raynos you really shouldn't assume JavaScript cannot run in different context when that's possible such as chrome apps and extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Disregarding the security issue that you cannot "browse" local files with a website, your question should be answered:

When requesting a PERSISTENT filesystem you have to request a quota in first.
Try that instead:

```
window.storageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, 
    function(grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
    }, 
    errorHandler
);
```