# HTML5 code not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.requestFileSystem not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803064/window-requestfilesystem-not-working)

Following is the code to generate a csv file using any data from HTML page. In my case, I hvae a variable history in which I have data collected from a HTML table.

By this code, I can download the generated csv file in my computer. this code is working fine in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. I need to run it in firefox too.

This code is from HTML5

You can try this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4EJP/3/)

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
        fs.root.getFile('history_tracker.csv', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            var builder = new WebKitBlobBuilder();

            builder.append(history);

            var blob = builder.getBlob('text/plain');

            fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
              window.open(fileEntry.toURL());
            };
            fileWriter.write(blob);
          }, errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
      }, errorHandler);
    }

    function errorHandler(e) {
      var msg = '';

      switch (e.code) {
        case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
          msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
          break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
          msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
          break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
          msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
          break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
          msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
          break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
          msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
          break;
            default:
          msg = 'Unknown Error';
          break;
                };
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is currently the only browser to implemented the HTML5 Filesystem API. See the supported browsers note in the html5rocks article.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a nonstandard API: the filesystem API.  It's not part of HTML5, and may not ever become standardized; right now it's just a proprietary Chrome extension to the standards.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that since the function is called window.webkitRequestFileSystem(), that it isn't part of the HTML5 standard. The webkit engine is only used by a few browsers including Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox. You'll want to lookup the API offered by Firefox.