# Save files within chrome extension using known path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extension, but I really have this problem.
I need to save some file in the background script, the path I want to save is depending on the content I want to save(so it somehow dynamic).

I check the chrome.fileSystem at [chrome extension doc](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html#method-retainEntry), turns out it will request user to choose a dir to save the file. But I want to save files automatically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Long story short: You cannot save files on the user's filesystem without user-interaction (and even then several restrictions apply). Take a look at **[this question's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802032/how-can-a-chrome-extension-save-many-files-to-a-user-specified-directory)** answers for a little more insight on the possible options (and their limitations).