# How to create a named file in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Searching for an example of how to create a local file in chrome as well as read it back, the only link in the docs really is: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access

Here is the link to the docs for chrome.FileSystem: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

conspicuously absent is how to create a file.

The function getWriteableEntry seems to create a new entry but requires one.  How do you get in effect the root directory of the google chrome area?

```
chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(Entry entry, function callback)
```

I would like a pointer to an example showing how to write a string to a file in local storage, and how to read that back in.

Is it really something that requires user input?  I thought that was no longer true with a chrome extension: [Saving files in a Chrome App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787301/saving-files-in-a-chrome-app)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: AFAIK *extensions* can't access local file system outside of the [extension package directory](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/