# Read from file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome-extension

Hello I am developing a Google Chrome extension and need to read some information from a .txt file, so I did some research but i just found how to choose a file and read from it, but what I need to do is just read from a path, like c:\file.txt, not choose it and after read. I would really appreciate if any one could help me, thanks.

Comment: you cant http://stackoverflow.com/a/19813816/4769440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime) to read local files if they are inside the app package directory using getPackageDirectoryEntry.

If you are trying to read random files then it's not possible without the user selecting it, js is sandboxed.